# JHipster - Why does AuthorizedFeignClient and stuff not generated within the gateway

Tags: jhipster

I noticed I can use @AuthorizedFeignClient annotation from my microservices, but this code is not generated on the gateway.

Is there a reason for that? How do I communicate from the gateway to uServices from the backend without these classes?

Comment: Based on the comment https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/7492#issuecomment-381496359, I think it's just not implemented yet

Comment: Dumb me, I haven't got the reaction to search within generator-jhipster repo issues. You're the one Jon, thank you! I'll try to test the Feign integration within my Gateway and PR on Jhipster if I succeed.